# Sudden Oil consumption increase

Tags: fuel-consumption, chrysler, chrysler-300c, oil-consumption

There is increased oil consumption in a        2009 chrysler 300c that has the 5.7    Hemi motor .There are no oil stains on the garage floor .There is an apparent fuel consumption increase which we will quantify later .The car is in UBER use .I think that it is far to young to need rings at 203000Km              .An engine recon would be a financial disaster .What could it be ? Has anybody had a bad 300c experience ? Does the 5.7 have any known weak points? I am in denial and will investigate tomorrow surely the car has a good rep .

Comment: What year of car are you talking about? Is this the HEMI engine?

Comment: And how many miles on the engine, year of vehicle, maintenance history (wrt oil changes). What part of the world is this car operated in? Is there smoke from the tailpipe? If so on acceleration or deceleration? What is the current oil consumption per 1000 miles? With the information given it could be nearly anything. Additional info will help narrow it down.